# Firebase + React Native: how to get all the data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So I want to receive all these datas to my code and then render them

[image]

I read a lot of other questions and topics as well as firebase documentation, but still didn't get how to do it correctly

So what I have now are this database above and this code below.

But the problem is that it renders only white screen and I can't find my mistake.

How can I fix it?

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class Messagesss extends React.Component {
  state = {
   loading: false,
   users: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
   var allMessages = firebase.database().ref(`/users`);
   allMessages.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  this.setState({ users: snapshot.val(), loading:false })
})
}

 renderItem({item}) {
   return (
     <View style = {styles.contactContainer}>
      <View style={styles.userRow}>
        <View style={styles.userImage}>
          <Avatar
            width={60}
            rounded
            source={{
              uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Matterhorn_from_Domhütte_-_2.jpg/1200px-Matterhorn_from_Domhütte_-_2.jpg"
            }}
          />
        </View>
         <View>
          <View style={styles.emailBackground}>
           <Text
             style = {styles.contact} >
             {item.email}
           </Text>
           </View>
           <Text
              style = {styles.message} >
              Da inne lauft öpis...
           </Text>
          </View>
         </View>
       </View>
     )
 }

 render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="dodgerblue" />
      </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <Header
       centerComponent={{ text: 'Nachrichten', style: { color: '#FF0000', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' } }}
       outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}
     />
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.users}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.uid}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug or console.log data? Maybe you got the data, but the styles is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @anhtu I tried to console.log data and I found out, that the array is empty. But still don’t get why it’s empty.

Comment: Try to debug around `once` statement.